# How to prevent user to change javascript button disable() function?

Tags: javascript, php

Creating a forum on localhost. When user clicks on the button to post the question, my javascript function disables it(when the question was asked) to prevent question spamming. Everything okay with that, but:

Here is the code which is in /scripts/scriptname.js

```
function disable() {
   document.getElementById("submit-img").disabled = true;
}
disable();
```

If the user changes this code above to false, the user can post various questions, because he can change it to: .disabled = false

Comment: you cannot enforce this from client side, you will have to setup a serverside check to prevent such abuse. Even if you manage to disable the button, someone can just replay the API request and create multiple questions

Comment: What exactly is you want. You want to filter the duplicate questions asked on the website?

Comment: No, when the user asks a question, my code opens a new tab and shows the question there. Then, the tab that includes the form to ask the question remains but the button to ask the question turns into disabled- so the user can't ask the question unless he refreshes. But, the user can also change the source code and post it by making document.getElementById("submit-img").disabled = false; that's my problem, I am asking how to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot. Any form of front-end validation will not protect your server or database from spammers hence a back-end validation is required. Depending on what back-end language and framework you're using, you'll need to keep track of the user's IP address (assuming there is no form of authentication) and set a timestamp in your database that will prevent that specific IP address from sending requests to the endpoint you're trying to protect.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about with it is wrong. You should allow only registered and verified user to access and post content to your forum. Your implementation is javascript base so it can be hacked.

It should be done server side. At least, you should create a database where you should track all users activities via something like their login session data, ip address, emails etc. You can set a counter to count number of content to be posted by users on a particular time and then banned or stop any offending user.

While double registration by users are not easily avoided but you can limit it by asking each registered user to verify their email via a link sent to them upon registration.

You can also set up a captcha eg Google recaptcha to limit bots access

Infact, what you are trying to implement is too broad from security point of view.

If security is not much of your interest you can try this little sample code below. The tracking is based on session. **just remember that if users clears session cookies, he can still bypass**

Based on your request. You can use session to track users submission count. This is not security proof as I stated earlier but it will give you an insight into building your own app. However its far better that doing it in a javascript which your users/clients can easily abused....

The code below  will hide submit button if user submit more than 2 times

```
<form action="" method="post">
Enter name<input type="text" name="uname">

<?php

error_reporting(0);
session_start();

if($_SESSION['att'] >=2){
// hide submit button
}else{
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
}
?>
</form>


<?php
//session_start();

// set up session counter
echo $_SESSION['att'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
$name='';
$uname='';

$name = $_POST["uname"];
echo $_SESSION['uname'] = $name; 

?>
```

Comment: Actually, thanks for the response, but as you said it, only registered users can ask questions. And yeah, I solved the problem by using php-like the one in the reddit, the user can ask questions in each 10 minutes so this will prevent spamming.

Comment: am glad you like it